# Cant stop youtube video when the wrappers hides

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have 2 divs that need to show hide. One with images, one with youtube video.

```
<div class="gallery-video-wrapper">
     <iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="430" height="323" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="gallery-images">
    <img src="image1.jpg" />
rest of the jquery gallery code...
</div>
```

By default only the video is shown. On click on

```
<a href="#" class="show-gallery">Show Images</a>
```

I want to show the gallery which i managed to do. But if the video is played i cant seem to stop it unless i remove the whole div. and if do that i don't know how to put it back.

This is the script i have so far:

```
$('.show-gallery').click(stop, function() {

        $('.gallery-video-wrapper').fadeOut();
        $('.gallery-images').fadeIn(function() {
            $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
                display_back_and_forward : true,
                display_next_and_prev : true,
                update_window_hash : false,
                scroll_jump : 0,
                thumb_opacity : 1
            });
        });
    });
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But if the video is played i cant seem to stop it unless i remove the
>   whole div. and if do that i don't know how to put it back.*

have you tried using `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`?

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

you can also try to `.hide()` the div, and `.show()` it later

Comment: The detach thing solves the playing in background, but how can i return it later?

Comment: store the element you are detaching in a variable, like `var videoplayer = $('#videoplayer').detach()`. later, just append it where you want: `videoplayer.appendTo('body')`